5 bulb chandelier on a dimmer switch flickering on full power
I bought my house about 8 months ago, originally built in 1970s or so I believe. There is a 5 bulb chandelier in the dining room on a dimmer switch. I wasn't having any issues with it but I left town for about four days and just returned last night, now, whenever I put the dimmer on full power, the chandelier flickers then dims to about 50% power. I haven't changed anything about it, other than one bulb about 4 months ago and I can't quite figure out what is going on.
I saw one similar question but it was specifically related to flickering on full power after updating to an LED dimmer switch and bulbs and I have done neither of those things.
(LED bulb dims and flickers when turned up to max position on sliding dimmer switch)
Not sure what other information would be helpful, feel free to let me know if anything needs added, unfortunately I do not know the manufacturer of the chandelier or bulbs, or even the exact age

Possible the dimmer switch is wearing out.  Get a new dimmer, turn off the breaker for that circuit and replace.  Take pictures of how the old switch is wired up before undoing the wires.

Do you have LEDs, incandescents, or something else?

I believe they are incandescent

Dimmer switches will wear out in time. With the power off, remove the switch and connect the two wires together and turn on the power. If the light operates correctly, it a good sign that the dimmer is bad. Replace the dimmer with the correct one and verify the type and  wattage of the bulbs you're using.

Couldn't directly connecting the wires like that lead to a potential issue or overload? I'm by no means an electrician but I thought directly connecting wires to close a circuit was a bad idea?

As long as there are only two wires on the switch, a direct connection is fine. (3 connected wires is different.) Just be sure to take pictures before disassembly and be sure to flip the correct circuit breaker — that’ll be your switch.

Thanks, I'll give it a shot after work today

@murrag  A simple switch is connecting two wires together.  It just uses a piece of metal behind plastic to keep your fingers from the two live wires.

Followed your instructions @JACK, its just a dimmer switch going out, much appreciated
